# Using exclude() in Django query does not exclude

Tags: django

I want to query my model to return all entries that have today's date, and their `code` field is not null or empty. I have the following code:

Model:

```
class Model(models.Model):
   ...
   date = models.DateField(blank=False)
   code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

View:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
query = Model.objects.filter(date=today).exclude(code__isnull=True)
print(query)
    for obj in query:
        print(obj.auth)
        print(type(obj.field))
```

**Output**

```
<QuerySet [<Model: 2020-07-20 Object1>, <Model: 2020-07-20 Object2>]>
   
                # <- this is part of the result but it's empty
<class 'str'>
AUTH_ugxpb35mde
<class 'str'>
```

Even though the "auth" field of my code is empty, it's not being excluded e.g. why is an empty field not null (as shown in the output)?. What concept am I missing?

I have also tried querying as but it doesn't produce the desired output either:

```
...
query = Model.objects.exclude(code__isnull=True, date__lt=today)
...
```

**Output**

```
<QuerySet [<MerchantBilling: 2020-07-14 Object1>, <MerchantBilling: 2020-07-15 Object1>, <MerchantBilling: 2020-07-15 Object2>, <MerchantBilling: 2020-07-16 Object1>, <MerchantBilling: 2020-07-16 Object2>, <MerchantBilling: 2020-07-20 Object1>, <MerchantBilling: 2020-07-20 Object2>]>

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>
AUTH_1237hjjzqq
<class 'str'>
AUTH_ugxpb35mde
<class 'str'>

<class 'str'>
AUTH_ugxpb35mde
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it using this:

```
query = Model.objects.filter(date=today).exclude(code='')
```